# discord.py Search for files in deractory

Tags: python

Im pretty new to python and im trying to code a discord bot which searches for files but it wont work. I attached a image with all my files on replit.com

```
@bot.command()
async def search(ctx, file_name):
    search_result = 'Search Results:'
    from os import listdir
    for file in listdir('ArkFiles/Dinos'):
        if file_name in file.lower():
            search_result = search_result+'\n'+file
    if search_result == 'Search Results:':
        await ctx.send('Error: Not matched with any file.')
    else:
        await ctx.send(search_result)
```

[Screenshot of my Replit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3CUI.png)

Comment: Hi! Please explain what "it does not work" means. Do you get an error? What is the expected behaviour and what does your program actually do?

Comment: Hi, it looks like that your line is not correctly indented, remove a space from line 31 in the screenshot.

Comment: @infinitezero so i solved the error i rewrtote the code and it worked now i have a other issue as answer here in this post

Answer (score 1):

1. **Error:** `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

> This error usually comes up when you are using a mix of spaces and
> tabs for [indentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp) in Python (which is often caused by copy-pasting
> code from somewhere else). To fix, convert all tabs to 4 spaces in
> your text editor. E.g. in [Atom](https://atom.io/), the 'Whitespace: Convert Tabs to
> Spaces' command that you can find with Cmd+Shift+P works nicely. (@charlesalexandre-roy on Grepper)

2. **Personal recommendation №1:** Avoid using `from os import listdir` in the middle of your code. For the sake of readability place all imports in the beginning of the code.
3. **Personal recommendation №2:** Avoid using `Repl.it`, `Google Colab` or any other online IDEs for coding in Python. They have very limited capabilities when it comes to running programs on a bigger scale. Besides they are much slower compared to running Python scripts locally. I highly recommend installing [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/pycharm/download/#section=windows). Besides being open-source, it also has all the things you need when working on a Python project.

---

Answer (score -1):

So i solved the problem and now i need to know how i can do smth else.
My Code works currently and it looks like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def search(ctx, file_name):
    search_result = ''
    from os import listdir
    for file in listdir('ArkFiles/Dinos'):
        if file_name in file.lower():
            search_result = search_result+'\n'+file
    if search_result == 'Search Results:':
        await ctx.reply('Error: Not matched with any file.')
    else:
         embed = discord.Embed(title="Here is a list of  files I found in the current Ark files that include "#term which got searched":")
         embed.add_field(name='** **', value= search_result, inline=False)
         await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
```

So after include should be "term which got searched" i really have no clue what i should put inthere.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).